# Distributed wifi for medium-sized office

Tags: networking, wifi

We're soon to be moving into office of 400m² that's an odd U shape. We'd like wireless coverage across the whole thing. It seems to me that distributed wi-fi is the answer (a controller managing two dumb APs). I can't for the life of me find any vendor that has a solution in the price range a medium-sized business. Perhaps I'm searching for the wrong thing? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Give Juniper a look.  They have a small controller (supports 4 AP's) for $900 full retail, you can find it as low as $650 if you look around.  I am a fan of the Cisco line, worked with them for 4 years and they are a dream to manage, lots of online reference material.

Answer (score 0):

Meru runs some good bundle pricing on their smaller controllers.  I think you need to call the reseller in your area to get pricing.  I have 5 of their radios in a 10,000 square foot office and they work great.

Answer (score 0):

Mikrotik. You get a lot more, but this is also something they support and their prices are - very interesting.